# Dynamically Get Value of Query String and Add to Objects using javascript and/or jquery

Tags: javascript, query-string

I'm trying to loop through any given pair of key and value query strings and add their values to objects already on the page. I'm only able to get this to partially work. Currently, this code is only defining the last pair key/value query strings.

For instance, the following querystring: index.html?example1=something&example2=somethingElse

Only returns "example2" and "somethingElse" into the first set of input fields and the rest are undefined. Obviously, there lies the issue, but I'm stumped on how to do this.

This will be hard to illustrate in jsfiddle, as I'm unaware of how to add query strings to a jsfiddle page, but I'll share my code, nonetheless:

```js
var queryString = unescape(location.search);

//remove the ?
queryString = queryString.substring(1);

//split querystring into key/value pairs
var pairs = queryString.split("&");

//load the pairs into a collection
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
  //split into key/value pair by splitting on =
  var keyValuePair = pairs[i].split("=");

  //keyValuePair[0] = key
  //keyValuePair[1] = value

  //alert("Value = " + keyValuePair[1] );
}

document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = keyValuePair[0];
document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value = keyValuePair[1];
/*document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value = keyValuePair[2];
document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value = keyValuePair[3];
document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[4].value = keyValuePair[4];
document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[5].value = keyValuePair[5];
document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[6].value = keyValuePair[6];
document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[7].value = keyValuePair[7];*/
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>Define Criteria</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="expression-forms">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-left" for="inputPassword">Field Label 1</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_01" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg1" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label text-center" >=</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_02" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg2" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn" type="button" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-left" for="inputPassword">Field Label 2</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_03" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg3" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label text-center" >=</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_04" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg4" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-left" for="inputPassword">Field Label 3</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_05" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg5" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label text-center" >=</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_06" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg6" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-left" for="inputPassword">Field Label 4</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_07" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg7" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label text-center" >=</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input name="field_08" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="fg8" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2po6wL55/

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of it had to do with the `keyValuePair` scoping, another had to do with how you were indexing the elements when putting them in the input fields. Here's an updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2po6wL55/4/

And the replaced code:

```
//var queryString = unescape(location.search);
var queryString = unescape('?example1=something&example2=somethingElse');

var keyValuePair = {};

//remove the ?
queryString = queryString.substring(1);

//split querystring into key/value pairs
var pairs = queryString.split("&");

//load the pairs into a collection
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    //split into key/value pair by splitting on =
    keyValuePair[i] = pairs[i].split("=")
};

document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = keyValuePair[0][0];

document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value = keyValuePair[0][1];

document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value = keyValuePair[1][0];

document.getElementById("expression-forms").getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value = keyValuePair[1][1];
```

`keyValuePair` could also be an array, I just forgot to change it, but it works either way. Each time you access a pair in the loop, you're pushing a new array on. You were only indexing the first dimension of that array when replacing the values, when it should have been `[pairIndex][pairHalf]`.

Comment: What would be the kayValuePair sequencing be if I wanted to populate the other fields? keyValuePair[0][0];?

Comment: If you're using an array, it's built like: `[[key, value], [key, value], [key, value]]`, so you would would use `keyValuePair[2][0]` for the first field, and `keyValuePair[2][1]` for the second, and that pattern repeats.

Comment: No prob, added clarity anyway :)